# Source Control - Visual Studio Code is not tracking file changes

Tags: visual-studio-code, version-control

vscode source control stopped working. I tried removing git and initializing a new git repo, I tried deleting the whole project and staring a new project, I tried disabling all extension and restarting vscode but nothing worked.

It stopped tracking any file changes, not showing the M and U letters in the explorer tree when I add or modify files, or the heat map next to number line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B04Xf.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QisTh.png

It only seems to notice the changes to my project when I hit the refresh button in the source control tab but still nothing changes in the explorer tree and no heat map on the file itself.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdTfQ.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYdJd.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

installed the latest update of vscode and made a new project. It seems to be working now, still have no idea why It stopped working then.

Answer (score 0):

while you are using track change option you have to select
"selection margin" display option otherwise it won't work

Comment: How can I enable this option?